# Manually configure indentation monodevelop

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, monodevelop

I'm a long-time Windows user, going with Linux mostly for the terminal and for networking purposes.  The thing is, I really love the VisualStudio code editor window.  I don't really handle projects using an IDE, but the way VS highlights and does indentation on c/c++ files is perfect, in my opinion.

For one, is it possible to have Monodevelop do c++ highlighting (new, using, namespace, etc.)?

But to my main question:
Can I manually configure how Monodevelop handles indents?  I'd like it to automatically insert an indent after a newline following a curly brace or a conditional statement as well as un-indent when the closing brace is provided, if the insertion point is not already aligned correctly.

Comment: Umm, mine does that by default (also C++ syntax highlighting). What version of MonoDevelop on which distro are you using?

Comment: MD ver. 3.0.3.2 on Kali Linux.

Comment: Aha, mine is 2.4.2. Maybe C++ support has been removed? Or been put in a separate package? Is there a package named something like monodevelop-cpp for Kali?

Comment: Not that I can find...

Comment: Oh, well, if it had been removed/outsourced, there probably wouldn't be an option to start a new C++ project in the first place. Anyway, it does automatic in- and outdenting plus syntax highlighting here, so it definitely is possible. But I've no idea how to configure it, sorry.

Comment: Highlighting fixed.  Apparently, it depends on the file extension, which is bupkes, because it really holds no bearing on anything in Linux.  So .cc instead of .c, but indentations are still an issue.

Comment: The extension is however also used by gcc to determine the language unless you explicitly specify it using `-x`, so the IDE taking it into account to select the syntax highlighter is not too surprising. How does the indenting behave for you?

Comment: I have to indent manually.  It will stay at an indented level when I do a newline, but I kind of wish it would insert them when it makes sense to, like immediately following a conditional header.  Also, the extensions don't make a difference with the GNU compiler.  `gcc` by default compiles C code and `g++` by default interprets source as c++ code, at least on my machine, regardless of extension.